# Impacket & dpkt sending features?

Tags: python, networking, dpkt, impacket

Is there any support for sending packets in impacket or dpkt libraries?

I was able to find examples of sniffing, interpreting and constructing packets using these libraries, but they don't seem to support sending over network interfaces.

Ping example of impacket library uses standard socket library in python to send the packet.
Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dpkt does not have any built-in way to send packets. Once you construct the packet, you will need to use a RAW socket to send out packets. [Here](https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/08/25/dpkt-tutorial-1-icmp-echo/) is a good example, which shows you how to send a raw ICMP packet constructed using dpkt.